# switch menu, can't select a case and can't get it to display

Tags: java, menu, switch-statement

On the 1st block of code I need to make a menu that displays 3 types of vehicles, then the user types the number of which vehicle he'll choose, after that he needs to be redirected to another menu that displays a list of vehicles and choose one, then fill up a couple questions. It's in Spanish i know, sorry ;__;

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Vehic {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int vehic;int comp;
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("¡Hola!,\nEscriba el numero de la clase de "
                + "vehiculo que desea comprar:\n1.Autos \n2.Camionetas "
                + "\n3.Motocicletas");
        vehic=sc.nextInt();

        switch(vehic) {
            case 1:System.out.println("-AUTOMOVILES-\nEscriba el numero de "
                    + "un automovil para añadirlo al carrito1. 542315 Tesla "
                    + "X 2017 4500km \n2. 892567Honda Civic 2015 4200km "
                    + "\n3. 634563 Tesla Z 2016 5600km \n4. 787256 Nissan "
                    + "Sentra 1000km \n5. 646464 Tesla Y 2300km \n6. 359812 "
                    + "BMW Hunter 7800km \n7. 159327 Mini Cooper 4500km \n8."
                    + " 496251 Jeep 6000km");
            comp=sc.nextInt();

            while(comp<8){
                switch(comp){
                    case 1:
                        String nom;
                        String ap;
                        int id;
                        String model;
                        System.out.println("Gracias por su compra!, "
                                + "ingrese su nombre:");
                        nom=sc.next();
                        System.out.println("Ahora, ingrese su apellido");
                        ap=sc.next();
                        System.out.println("Por ultimo, ingrese su ID de "
                                + "comprador:");
                        id=sc.nextInt();
                        System.out.println("Ingrese el modelo que adquirio");
                        model=sc.next();
                        System.out.println("-RECIBO- \nModelo adquirido:"
                                + "542315 Tesla X 2017 4500km"+model
                                +" \n Almacenamos esta informacion de usted,"
                                + " \nNombre:"+nom+"\nApellido:"+ap+"ID:"+id);
                        break;


                    case 2:
                        System.out.println("-CAMIONETAS-\nEscriba el numero "
                                + "de la camioneta para añadirla al carrito1. "
                                + "263785 Tesla X 2017VAN 4500km \n2. 892567"
                                + "Honda Civic 2015VAN 4200km \n3. 634563 "
                                + "Tesla Z 2016VAN 5600km \n4. 787256 "
                                + "Nissan Sentra VAN1000km \n5. 646464 "
                                + "Tesla YVAN 2300km \n6. 359812 BMW "
                                + "HunterVAN 7800km \n7. 159327 Mini "
                                + "CooperVAN 4500km \n8. 496251 JeepVAN "
                                + "6000km");
                        comp=sc.nextInt();

                        while(comp<8) {
                            switch(comp){
                                case 1:
                                    String Nom;
                                    String Ap;
                                    int Id;
                                    System.out.println("Gracias por su "
                                            + "compra!, ingrese su nombre:");
                                    Nom=sc.next();
                                    System.out.println("Ahora, ingrese su apellido");
                                    Ap=sc.next();
                                    System.out.println("Por ultimo, ingrese su ID de comprador:");
                                    Id=sc.nextInt();
                                    System.out.println("Ingrese el modelo que adquirio");
                                    model=sc.next();
                                    System.out.println("-RECIBO- \nModelo adquirido:"
                                            +model+"\n Almacenamos esta "
                                            + "informacion de usted, \nNombre:"
                                            +Nom+"\nApellido:"+Ap+"ID:"+Id);
                                    break;
                                case 3:
                                    System.out.println("-MOTOCICLETAS-\n"
                                            + "Escriba el numero de la "
                                            + "camioneta para añadirla al "
                                            + "carrito1. 378265 Harley "
                                            + "Davidson 1995 4500km \n2. 736259"
                                            + "Instict 2006 4200km \n3. 264254 "
                                            + "Harley Davidson 2016 5600km \n4. "
                                            + "265731 Italika 3014 1000km \n5. "
                                            + "852645 JetX 2300km \n6. "
                                            + "356425Instict Hunter 7800km "
                                            + "\n7. 3592145 Italika 2006 4500km "
                                            + "\n8.234781 Harley Davidson 2008 6000km");
                                    comp=sc.nextInt();

                                    while(comp<8) {
                                        switch(comp){
                                            case 1:
                                                String NOm;
                                                String AP;
                                                int ID;
                                                System.out.println("Gracias "
                                                        + "por su compra!, ingrese su nombre:");
                                                NOm=sc.next();
                                                System.out.println("Ahora, ingrese su apellido");
                                                AP=sc.next();
                                                System.out.println("Por ultimo, ingrese su ID de comprador:");
                                                ID=sc.nextInt();
                                                System.out.println("Ingrese el modelo que adquirio");
                                                model=sc.next();
                                                System.out.println("-RECIBO- \nModelo adquirido:"
                                                        +model+"\n Almacenamos esta informacion de usted, \nNombre: "
                                                        +NOm+"\nApellido:"+AP+"ID:"+ID);
                                                break;
                                        }
                                    }

                            }
                        }
                }

            }

        }
    }
}
```

First off, I can't select the 3rd case and don't know why, also when I select 1 of the 3 cases I can't get it to display and be able to answer the questions

Comment: add breaks after statements within each case: switch(variable){ case 0: your statement; break; case 1: your statement; break; etc..

Comment: theres a piece of unreached code in every case hen i do that :/

Answer (score 0):

the problem with your code (I guess) is the syntax and arrangement.
see... 
you should follow a **standard** model for your **while**(s) and **Switch**(s).
the while should be like this:

```
while (condition){
//codes
}
```

please pay attention to the **accolades/braces** and **parenthesis**

the accolade should be close exactly where your specific codes in the while loop ends.

also the form of switch should be like this:

```
switch (variable){
case X:
//codes
break;
case Y:
//codes
break;
default:
//codes
break;
}
```

you will find out the problems and others can help you better this way...
thanks and hope your success. @};-